# How not to hardcode the value of some correlation_id within headers to get required response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to grab different product names from this [webpage](https://www.rockwellautomation.com/search/ra-en-US;keyword=;startIndex=0;activeTab=Products;spellingCorrect=true;facets=;languages=en;locales=en_GLOBAL,en-US;sort=cat_a;isPLS=false;sessionID=6f6f0d02-7e32-b94d-7bcf-3fe9c45e2eaa;deepLinking=false). The product names, as in `0041-5053-005` generate dynamically. I can however scrape them using xhr with appropriate parameters.

It is necessary to use this following key and value within the headers to get the required data.

```
headers = {
    'client_secret': '',
    'client_id': '',
    'correlation_id': '0196e1f2-fb29-0modod-6125-fcbb6c2c69c1',
}
```

This is how I scraped the titles:

```
import requests

link = "https://es-be-ux-search.cloudhub.io/api/ux/v2/search?"

payload = {
    'queryText': '*:*',
    'role': 'rockwell-search',
    'spellingCorrect': 'true',
    'spellcheckPremium': '10',
    'segments': 'Productsv4',
    'startIndex': 0,
    'numResults': 10,
    'facets': '',
    'languages': 'en',
    'locales': 'en_GLOBAL,en-US',
    'sort': 'cat_a',
    'collections': 'Literature,Web,Sample_Code',
    'site': 'RA'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link,params=payload,headers=headers)
    for item in r.json()['response']['docs']:
        print(item['catalogNumber'])
```

I've noticed that the value of `client_secret` and `client_id` are static but the value of `correlation_id` changes.

> How can I use the value of `correlation_id` within the headers without hardcoding?

Comment: I think correlation_id here is something being generated by the web page, I wouldn't worry about it too much if its working.

Comment: You probably don't want to share that `client_secret` publicly - it's secret for a reason!

Answer (score 2):

The correlation ID is used to correlate HTTP requests between a client and server. [See this article for details on how that works](https://blog.rapid7.com/2016/12/23/the-value-of-correlation-ids/). It seems as though this API requires the correlation ID to be present in the HTTP headers, but doesn't change the response based on its value. The response is the same if you give an empty string:

```
headers = {
    'client_secret': '...',
    'client_id': '...',
    'correlation_id': '',
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @joedeandev. I could understand how `correlation ID` works but still I wish to know how I can parse the value of `correlation ID`. FYI, I can parse the value of `client_secret` and `client_id`, although I've hardcoded them here.

Comment: @robots.txt What do you mean, "parse the value"? If you want to get the value sent by the server during the request, you can try reading the headers in the response object: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.headers. The correlation ID is decided on and used by the server exclusively; I don't understand what it is exactly you need it for.